# Jobs are stuck in queue forever ( Condor - Parallel Universe )

Tags: condor

i've lately trying to configure HTcondor. I managed to submit serial (Vanilla Universe) jobs with no errors or problems. But when i try to submit parallel ( Parallel Universe ) jobs, it seems that the jobs get stucked in queue forever.

***Submit file Code :

```
universe = parallel
executable = SommeP
output = outputP.$(NODE)
error = errorP.$(NODE)
log = logP
machine_count = 4
should_transfer_files = yes
when_to_transfer_output = on_exit
queue
```

***Condor_q

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzfIS.png)

***Condor_status ( 1 Master 2 Slaves 6 Slots in total )
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcnU5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The admin of your condor pool will have to configure execute nodes to see your submit node as the Dedicated Scheduler before Parallel Universe jobs can be scheduled. See the Parallel Applications section in the manual for more information: http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/manual/current/2_9Parallel_Applications.html#SECTION00392000000000000000